# Laravel Two Values Must Be NOT Equal Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4 I'm trying to find not confirmation validation for input values. For example with `confirmation` we can check matching password and repassword and now I want to check contrary of two values. for example `A` must be not equal `A` in input values and after check in `rules` I must be return error. In this sample how to check that?

```html
<input id="starttime_range"
       name="starttime_range"
       type="text"
       class="form-control"
/>

<input id="finish_range"
       name="finish_range"
       type="text"
       class="form-control"
/>
```

`starttime_range` must be not equal with `finish_range`

My code :

```
public function postInsert()
{
    $rules = array(
        'starttime_range' => 'required|integer',
        'endtime_range' => 'required|integer|not:starttime_range',
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Would it make more sense to be sure `endtime_range` comes after `starttime_range`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want campare two diffrent value, than you have to use [different:](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-different)

```
 $rules = array(
    'starttime_range' => 'required|integer',
    'finish_range' => 'required|integer|different:starttime_range',
);
```

Comment: this is not working in Laravel v4.2 for different values its work fine but with deifferent values its also give same error